# How to distinguish "can" and "can't" pronunciation in American English?

Tags: differences, american-english, pronunciation

I am  a student in China learning American English.

I have listened to some videos and found it hard to distinguish *can* from *can’t*.  I am looking for some advice that may help me.

Comment: Try going through the treasure house of past questions on this site first. You can use the 'Search' box at the top.

Answer (score 5):

"Can" is usually pronounced /kən/ (with a schwa sound): as in "I can (/kən/) ride a bike". It is treated as a function word and as such, is unstressed.

"Can't" is pronounced /kænʔ/ (with a glottal stop replacing an expected /t/ sound) as in: "But, I can't (/kænʔ/) ride a horse."

The distinction for the listener is the unstressed schwa (/ə/) in "can" and the fully stressed /æ/ in "can't".

The exception to this is when "can" is at the end of a sentence: "Can (/kən/) you ride a bike?" "Yes, I can." (/kæn/). In this position "can" is stressed and is pronounced: /kæn/.

The negative response would be: "No, I can't." (/kænʔ/), pronounced (/kænt/) in careful speech.

Comment: Tks for your help

Comment: In many American dialects, including my own, stressed _can_ does not rhyme with _man_, but with _pen_. I.e, _Yes, I can!_ is pronounced /yɛsay'kɛn/. This means that stressed _can_ and _can't_ use different vowels, just like unstressed _can_ and _can't_

Comment: Here: ʔ Now you have no excuse to use question marks as an approximation.

Comment: @EMBLEM I've proposed an edit with your fix.